# Integer vs int: with regard to memory

Tags: java, integer, int

I was wondering if there is a difference in the memory occupied by 
`Integer n`, and `int n`.

I know `int n` occupies 4 bytes normally, how about `Integer n`

Comment: The only possible answer is "it depends".

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76549/how-are-integer-arrays-stored-internally-in-the-jvm although not stricly a duplicate.

Comment: @KerrekSB Can you elaborate on why "it depends?"

Comment: @craig: Because as you hinted at in your answer, it's totally up to the JVM implementation how much heap space it wants to take for each of those things.  If I'm not mistaken, there's nothing that would stop a compliant JVM from storing an `int` as 128 bits, as long as that decision doesn't leak out to the hosted program.  All you can know is that the "width" of `int` and `Integer` are the same; they can both represent the same number of values.

Comment: First of all depends on hardware: x86 (pointer "weights" 4 bytes) and x64 (pointer "weights" 8 bytes). Secondly it depends of JVM but I assume you imply Oracle JVM.

Comment: @craig: It's entirely possible that the JVM recognizes that a local `Integer` cannot possibly be used elsewhere and chooses to treat it like a plain `int`... or a really naive JVM could wrap *everything* and manage it through a GC. There's really no telling. Presumably you can concoct a situation in which an `int` requires a small amount of memory and an `Integer` causes a gcheap allocation, but the mechanics of this aren't under your control, and neither are they mandated by the language.

Comment: Great link: http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/object_memory_usage.shtml

Answer (score 54, accepted):

In general, the heap memory used by a Java object in Hotspot consists of:

- an object header, consisting of a few bytes of "housekeeping" information;
- memory for **primitive** fields, according to their size (int n->32 bits)
- memory for **reference** fields (4 bytes each)  (Integer n ->32 bits)
- padding: potentially a few "wasted" unused bytes after the object data, to make every object start at an address that is a convenient multiple of bytes and reduce the number of bits required to represent a pointer to an object.

as per the suggestion of Mark Peters I would like add the link below
http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/object_memory_usage.shtml

Comment: Upvote for being the only answer to qualify it with "in Hotspot".  But downvote for not citing your source.

Comment: thank for your suggestion and I have added the site link for more information.

Comment: Also note that in addition to the heap memory requirement for the object (which may well be "zero" if a cached instance is re-used many times, as happens with `Integer.valueOf(small)`), you still need to store the pointer to the object in your stack frame or containing object. That is another 32 or 64 bits, i.e. the pointer also is already at least as big as an `int`.

Comment: what is the reference fields used for?

Answer (score 11):

An Integer object in Java occupies 16 bytes.

I don't know whether running a 64- vs 32-bit JVM makes a difference. For *primitive types*, it **does not matter**. But I can not say for certain how the memory footprint of an *object* changes (if at all) under a 64-bit system.

You can test this for yourself here:

[Java Tip 130: Do you know your data size?](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip130.html?page=2)

Answer (score 8):

**int** is a primitive data type which takes **32 bits(4 bytes)** to store.

When your Java code uses the new operator to create an instance of a Java object, much more
data is allocated than you might expect.
For example, it might surprise you to know that the size ratio of an int value to an Integer object — the smallest object that can hold an int value — is
typically 1:4.

**Integer** is an object which takes **128 bits (16 bytes)** to store int value.

When we creates new Integer using new Operator it allocates memory as per follows.

1. **Class** Object(32 bits) - which consist of a pointer to the class information, which describes the object in our case its point to java.lang.Integer class
2. **Flags** (32 bits)- It is collection of flags that describes the state of object.
   Like is it has hash-code, is it array or not i.e. its Shape.
3. **Lock** (32 bits) - It stores synchronization information of object. whether the object currently synchronized or not.

Above 3 points are called as **metadata** of an Object.

4. Lastly metadata is followed by the Object **data** (32 bits) itself. In case of Integer its single int value.

All the above explanation is as per 32 bit processor architecture. It can differ from **JVM version** and **vendor**.

Comment: and a reference to the 16bytes, so another 4 bytes?

Answer (score 4):

For int: 4 bytes used per element without wrappers, and 16 per element with a wrapper.

A wrapped double reports as 24 bytes per element, with the actual double value as 64 bits (8 bytes).

For more details [here](http://www.glenmccl.com/tip_016.htm)

Comment: Link in answer is dead - *"404 Not Found"*.