# Java - Integer[] and int[] memory difference

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to get a general idea of the memory cost difference between an Integer array and int array. While there seems to be a lot of information out there about the differences between a primitive int and Integer object, I'm still a little confused as to how to calculate the memory costs of an int[] and Integer[] array (overhead costs, padding, etc).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419860/integer-vs-int-with-regard-to-memory

Comment: @bigdestroyer Thank you, but I'm asking about arrays in this case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Java, what is the best way to determine the size of an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object)

Comment: @ThomasJungblut: Is it?  Presumably an array of primitives involves almost no overhead, an array of references imposes the storage for all the references *as well as* the referred-to objects.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to storing the length of the array, an array of `int`s needs space for N 4-byte elements, while an array of `Integer`s needs space for N references, whose size is platform-dependent; commonly, that would be 4 bytes on 32-bit platforms or 8 bytes on 64-bit platforms.

As far as `int[]` goes, there is no additional memory required to store data. `Integer[]`, on the other hand, needs objects of type `Integer`, which could be all distinct or shared (e.g. through interning of small numbers implemented by the Java platform itself). Therefore, `Integer[]` requires up to N additional objects, each one containing a 4-byte `int`.

Assuming that all `Integer`s in an `Integer[]` array are distinct objects, the array and its content will take two to three times the space of an `int[]` array. On the other hand, if all objects are shared, and the memory costs of shared objects are accounted for, there may be no additional overhead at all (on 32-bit platforms) or the there would be a 2x overhead on 64-bit platforms.

Comment: Presumably the length also needs to be stored somewhere?

Comment: The absolute minimum size for an object is 16 bytes in any realistic JVM implementation, with 32 being more likely.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://vanillajava.blogspot.com.au/2011/07/java-how-much-memory-do-different.html)  is a comparison on jdk6u26 of the size of an array of 1024 `Integer`s as opposed to 1024 `int`s. Note that in the case of an`Integer[]` array containing low number `Integer`s, these can be shared with other uses of these `Integer`s in the JVM by the auto-box cache.