# Java heap - bigger than it needs to be

Tags: java, memory

My maths says the following Java program would need approx 8GB (2147483645 * 4 bytes) of RAM:

```
package foo;

public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int[] arr = new int[Integer.MAX_VALUE-2];
        Thread.sleep(500000L);
    }
}
```

This is backed up by observing the program when running:
[image: jvisualvm memory pic]

But unless you set the max heap to around 12.5GB, the program fails to start:

```
$ java -Xmx12000m -cp ./ foo.Foo
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at foo.Foo.main(Foo.java:5)
$ java -Xmx12500m -cp ./ foo.Foo
//this works
```

Can understand the need for a bit of wiggle-room but why do we need so much?

Comment: Explain "your maths"

Comment: Certainly your code contains more than `int[] arr = new int[Integer.MAX_VALUE-2];`. Without telling us what that is, it is hard to determine the problem.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419860/integer-vs-int-with-regard-to-memory

Comment: What?  This is a totally valid question about the arrangement of the Java heap, which does in fact require significantly more space than the largest object in it.

Comment: JVM itself needs some free space to breathe. If you REALLY need to allocate so much memory, you could try to search for off-heap allocation (e.g. using ByteBuffer).

Comment: bradimus: provided the full program, nothing else going on.
cricket_007: maths is basically just MAX_INT * 4btyes per int.
gusto2: I understand it need **some** space to breathe but why isn't 4GB enough?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its because of the MinHeapFreeRatio default value (which is 40%). If you want to "need" less then you have to specify it: e.g. 5% 
`-XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=5`

Also, you need to change memory allocated to the young generation as it plays a important role in memory allocation:

> After total available memory, the second most influential factor affecting garbage collection performance is the proportion of the heap dedicated to the young generation.

try this:

```
java -Xmx9g -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=1 -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -cp ./ foo.Foo
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/sizing.html

Comment: Nice answer with supporting documentation!