# ArrayList<Integer> vs ArrayList<String> - both storing values from 0 to 9 .. which takes more memory?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, integer

I was asked this question... `ArrayList` of `Integer` vs `ArrayList` of `String` - both storing values from `0` to `9` ... which takes more memory?

Comment: It actually depends on how values are initialized.

Comment: @lexicore .. for Integer it's like add(1) .. and for string it's like add("1") ..

Comment: If the integer values are between -128 and 127, then an ArrayList<Integer> only stores a reference to a shared object. If the strings are all constants in a class file, the same applies.

Comment: To close-voters: it is perfectly clear what is being asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a test result using this [tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object/40764295#40764295), it shows that `ArrayList<Integer>` occupies less memory:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> integerArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> stringArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        integerArrayList.add(i);
        stringArrayList.add(String.valueOf(i));
    }
    System.out.println(RamUsageEstimator.sizeOf(integerArrayList));  // 240
    System.out.println(RamUsageEstimator.sizeOf(stringArrayList));  // 560
}
```

Comment: This does not consider string interning and caching of small integers.

Comment: @lexicore I did not look into the implemention of this tool. It might omit the cache or interning and not reach the second level in your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming lists are created as follows:

```
    List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
    integers.add(0);
    integers.add(1);
    // ...
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    strings.add("0");
    strings.add("1");
    // ...
```

There two levels of answering this question.

First is about knowing memory consumption of `Integer` and `String`.

> - [How much memory does a string use in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31206851/how-much-memory-does-a-string-use-in-java-8)
> - [Integer vs int: with regard to memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419860/integer-vs-int-with-regard-to-memory)

So, a `String` with one character takes 40 bytes (32 on Java 8).
An `Integer` takes 16 bytes.

On this level, list of strings takes more memory than list of integers.

On the second level you have to know that string literals are interned and boxing an `int` with `Integer.valueOf` uses cache for values between `-128` and at least `127`. So basically both `add("0")` and `add(0)` will use cached objects and one could say that no additional memory is used.

So depending on whether you consider string pool/integer cache, the answer is either "list of strings takes more memory" or "both lists take the same amount of memory".

If this is an interview question, you should probably give both answers.

ps. I personally wouldn't have known the size of `String` or `Integer` out of the head, but would have guessed `String` to take more memory.

Comment: Thanks @lexicore for such a detailed explanation. I don't know why people down voted my question. Not everyone knows everything.

Comment: @AnujTela Your question shows lack of research. Googling "java size of integer" or "java size of string" returns links to existing questions like I've found. I think this is why your question is downvoted.

Comment: @AnujTela If you feel that my answer helped you, you could upvote and/or [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Comment: I did google to find it out but could get the kind of explanation you have provided @lexicore. Never mind will take care hence forth.

Comment: A little bit weird. I use the tool in my answer to measure a single characher string, and got 48 bit(jdk9).