# Kotlin: Why is Sequence more performant in this example?

Tags: kotlin

Currently, I am looking into Kotlin and have a question about **Sequences vs. Collections**.

I read a [blog post](https://winterbe.com/posts/2018/07/23/kotlin-sequence-tutorial/) about this topic and there you can find this code snippets:

**List implementation:**

```
val list = generateSequence(1) { it + 1 }
    .take(50_000_000)
    .toList()

measure {
    list
        .filter { it % 3 == 0 }
        .average()
}
// 8644 ms
```

**Sequence implementation:**

```
val sequence = generateSequence(1) { it + 1 }
    .take(50_000_000)

measure {
    sequence
        .filter { it % 3 == 0 }
        .average()
}
// 822 ms
```

The point here is that the Sequence implementation is about 10x faster.

However, I do not really understand WHY that is. I know that with a Sequence, you do "lazy evaluation", but I cannot find any reason why that helps reducing the processing in this example.

However, here I know why a Sequence is generally faster:

```
val result = sequenceOf("a", "b", "c")
    .map {
        println("map: $it")
        it.toUpperCase()
    }
    .any {
        println("any: $it")
        it.startsWith("B")
    }
```

Because with a Sequence you process the data "vertically", when the first element starts with "B", you don't have to map for the rest of the elements. It makes sense here.

So, why is it also faster in the first example?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's look at what those two implementations are actually doing:

1. The List implementation first creates a `List` in memory with 50 million elements.  This will take a bare minimum of 200MB, since an integer takes 4 bytes.

   (In fact, it's probably *far* more than that.  As Alexey Romanov pointed out, since it's a generic `List` implementation and not an `IntList`, it won't be storing the integers directly, but will be ‘boxing’ them — storing references to `Int` objects.  On the JVM, each reference could be 8 or 16 bytes, and each `Int` could take 16, giving 1–2GB.  Also, depending how the `List` gets created, it might start with a small array and keep creating larger and larger ones as the list grows, copying all the values across each time, using more memory still.)

   Then it has to read all the values back from the list, filter them, and create **another** list in memory.

   Finally, it has to read all **those** values back in again, to calculate the average.
2. The Sequence implementation, on the other hand, doesn't have to store anything!  It simply generates the values in order, and *as it does each one* it checks whether it's divisible by 3 and if so includes it in the average.

   (That's pretty much how you'd do it if you were implementing it ‘by hand’.)

You can see that in addition to the divisibility checking and average calculation, **the List implementation is doing a massive amount of memory access, which will take a lot of time.**  That's the main reason it's far slower than the Sequence version, which doesn't!

Seeing this, you might ask why we don't use Sequences everywhere…  But this is a fairly extreme example.  Setting up and then iterating the Sequence has some overhead of its own, and for smallish lists that can outweigh the memory overhead.  So Sequences only have a clear advantage in cases when the lists are very large, are processed strictly in order, there are several intermediate steps, and/or many items are filtered out along the way (especially if the Sequence is infinite!).

In my experience, those conditions don't occur very often.  But this question shows how important it is to recognise them when they do!

Comment: Good answer overall, but I'd add two things: 1. Sequences are also much slower (if usable at all) if you need to do anything other than process each element in order. 2. The initial list is going to be much larger than 200MB because integers need to be boxed, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419860/integer-vs-int-with-regard-to-memory.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov: good points, thanks!  I should have spotted that the ints will be boxed.  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Leveraging lazy-evaluation allows avoiding the creation of intermediate objects that are irrelevant from the point of the end goal.

Also, the benchmarking method used in the mentioned article is not super accurate. Try to repeat the experiment with [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/).

Initial code produces a list containing 50_000_000 objects:

```
 val list = generateSequence(1) { it + 1 }
  .take(50_000_000)
  .toList()
```

then iterates through it and **creates another list** containing a subset of its elements:

```
.filter { it % 3 == 0 }
```

... and then proceeds with calculating the average:

```
.average()
```

---

Using sequences allows you to avoid doing all those intermediate steps. The below code doesn't produce 50_000_000 elements, it's just a representation of that 1...50_000_000 sequence:

```
val sequence = generateSequence(1) { it + 1 }
  .take(50_000_000)
```

adding a filtering to it doesn't trigger the calculation itself as well but derives a new sequence from the existing one (3, 6, 9...):

```
.filter { it % 3 == 0 }
```

and eventually, a terminal operation is called that triggers the evaluation of the sequence and the actual calculation:

```
.average()
```

---

Some relevant reading:

[Kotlin: Beware of Java Stream API Habits](https://4comprehension.com/kotlin-beware-of-java-stream-api-habits/)

[Kotlin Collections API Performance Antipatterns](https://4comprehension.com/kotlin-collections-api-performance-antipatterns/)

Comment: Well, compared to the second example in the OP, about the same number of operations are needed for filtering and then calculating the average when using a sequence or normal collection.

So, the reason why it's more performant is because no intermediate collections must be created, right?

Comment: @Aliquis it's not the same number of operations - in the first example, you need to iterate 50_000_000 times to create a filtered list and then proceed with calculating the average (which involves more iteration). In the second one, you just go straight for the average (you iterate the sequence once with filtering applied) without creating any redundant objects + possibly avoid autoboxing of ints