# What kind of memory will allocate in Java?

Tags: java, wrapper, primitive-types

Someone kindly clear my doubt on memory management in Java with the below-mentioned scenario.

When we assign value for the primitive data type variable the value will be stored in stack memory. Please do correct me if I understood the concept wrong.

As same like how the memory will allocate when do assign a value of a non-primitive data type as mentioned below.

```
Integer a = 3;
```

Will create a memory in stack or heap?

Comment: Either. It depends whether it is method-local or a class member.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419860/integer-vs-int-with-regard-to-memory

Comment: What happens when we declare the variable as method-local and class member? Please do clear my doubt on this. @user207421

Comment: You *can't* declare it as both method-local *and* a class member. One or the other. Make up your mind. But I now see you wrote `Integer` instead of `int`, which means the object is on the heap. I was referring to where the *variable* `a` is located.

Comment: Am not saying that I will declare the same variable as class member and method local. Am just asking how memory will allocate when we declare as class member and when we declare as method-local

Comment: If the variable `a` is method-local, it is on the stack. If it is a class member: on the heap. The `Integer` object it refers to is always on the heap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `a` will be either in heap or stack memory depending on what *kind* of variable it is:

- method or constructor local variables (including parameters) - on the stack
- instance variables (aka attributes or fields) - on the heap
- class variables - on the heap.

<sup>(For the sake of completeness, there are couple of obscure cases where a lambda or inner class refers to an effectively final local variable in an enclosing scope.  In those cases, a copy of the original variable's contents will be stored on the heap.)</sup>

The `Integer` object that represents the boxed value of `3` will be on the heap.

A copy of the reference to that object is stored *in* the variable `a` wherever that happens to be.   There may be other copies of that reference elsewhere in the JVM.