# Should I define class attributes primitives (when it's possible) or should I use a Wrapper class?

Tags: java, primitive-types

I am wondering if it's recommended always to use primitive types such as int when defining class attributes or should I wrapper classes instead of.

```
class Test{
    private final int id;

    /**
     * Class constructor
     * @param id
     */
    Test(int id) {
      this.id = id;
    }
  }
```

Comment: How else would `id` be defined?

Comment: So wouldn't your "wrapper class" have the primitive type in that case, breaking your proposed best practice?

Comment: Using of boxed variables makes sense if they can be `null`

Comment: By "wrapper class", do you mean `Integer` instead of `int`?  If so, it kind of depends.  In any situation where you don't want a default value, or when you want to allow null values, using the class wrapper instead of the associated primitive is preferred.

Comment: You mean `int` vs `Integer` ? In most cases it is easier and faster to just use primitives (IMHO) though the wrapper classes do have their advantages. For example `Boolean` can be `null` which basically gives the boolean "true-false" construct a third state. I guess it depends only on your use case. An `id` for example might be so simple that `int` is sufficient.

Comment: also: The Wrapper classes provide a nice set of methods you can use on the values!

Comment: I am asking if to defining class attributes should I use int or Integer in cases like these.

Comment: @LeandroMaro And the answer is that it depends on what you want to do. There is no one general answer.

Comment: maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8419860/896249) can be of interest to you - it discusses the usage of memory of the wrapper classes

Comment: @GameDroids it's the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what you need to do... If it's important to you to hold null values so you should use wrappers... Else you could as well use primitive... If you don't know if you need null or not then it's better to use primitives to avoid getting NPE.