# Calculating memory requirements for HashMap in Java

Tags: java, memory, hashmap

I have a ConcurrentHashMap like so:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> fruitMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

The key is a `String` of 10 characters, the value is an `Integer`.

Assuming there is no other memory consuming code in my application, how do I calculate the number of entries that can be stored in the HashMap on a server with 10GiB memory?

It'll be great if you can mention how we can calculate it for both Java 7 and Java 8 or later.

PS: I found [this](https://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/), but I didn't understand how the 6.75KB memory usage for hashmap of 100 ints mapped to ints was arrived at.

Comment: _it depends_ on the JVM version, on how big your heap is going to be, on some enabled/disabled flags. there is no `X` answer. And of course `HashMap` is not assignable to `ConcurrentHashMap`

Comment: And you will not get an exact number, but a ballpark figure, is that enough for you, e.g. 10M entries vs. 100m entires vs. 1B entries!?

Comment: 6.75KB is because, its not the primitive type that gets stored but the Integer objects which has some overhead. Refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419860/integer-vs-int-with-regard-to-memory . Additionally, hash map internally stores data in buckets...All keys that maps to same hash code will be in same bucket. That too has some overhead.

Comment: @luk2302 why do you say that? of course you can compute the exact size under a specific JVM version with specific flags enabled.

Comment: @Eugene The exact size will depend on the exact content (effect on buckets, chains, etc), load factor, concurrency level, initial size, etc, so it is hard to generalize.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel agreed, my point was that for a very specific case - this is totally doable.

Comment: If this answered your question, you can accept it.

Answer (score 5):

I will only provide you an example against `jdk-15` using [JOL](https://github.com/openjdk/jol) (that is the only reliable tool I would ever trust for this), for a `ConcurrentHashMap` with 10 entries, it is up to you from there.

```
Map<String, Integer> throttleMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

for(int i = 0; i< 10; ++i){
    throttleMap.put((""+i).repeat(10), i);
}

System.out.println( GraphLayout.parseInstance((Object)throttleMap).toFootprint());
```

This will output:

```
 COUNT       AVG       SUM   DESCRIPTION
    10        32       320   [B
     1        80        80   [Ljava.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node;
    10        16       160   java.lang.Integer
    10        24       240   java.lang.String
     1        64        64   java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap
    10        32       320   java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node
    42                1184   (total)
```

Understanding the above is not trivial. `Integer` is the easiest one:

- 12 bytes for two headers
- 4 bytes for the inner int field

So `16 bytes` for one, you have 10 of those, thus that line:

```
0        16       160   java.lang.Integer
```

an instance of `String` is more involved:

- 12 bytes for headers
- 4 bytes for `hash` field
- 1 byte for `coder` field
- 1 boolean for `hashIsZero` field ([what is hashIsZero?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2310498/why-doesnt-strings-hashcode-cache-0/64082954#64082954))
- 2 bytes for padding
- 4 bytes for `value` (`byte []`)

So `24 bytes` * 10:

```
 10        24       240   java.lang.String
```

That inner `byte []` will also add:

- 12 bytes of headers (`byte[]` is an Object).
- 4 bytes for the `length` field
- 10 bytes for each of the 10 bytes
- 6 bytes padding

Thus that:

```
 10        32       320   [B
```

Getting the overall picture is left as an exercise to you.

Comment: What are the other lines in the output indicating?

`10        32       320   [B`
`1        80        80   [Ljava.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node`
`1        64        64   java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap`

Does the final output line mean that a total 1184 bytes are used?:
`42                1184   (total)`

Comment: @seeker yes, that means 1184 bytes.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still wondering what's the difference between the 1st line in the output and 6th line in the output. Why is `320 bytes` used twice?

Comment: @seeker different Objects, exactly as the `Description` field says?

Comment: Right. I'm trying to understand what is `[B (bytes[])` used for and what is `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node` used for? One of them is probably to store the bucket information of the HashMap, but which one is it and what is the other one used for.

Comment: @seeker did you actually read what I wrote in the answer? I did explain what that `byte[]` is for, at the very end. That `Node` is an internal class in `CHM`, that stores the key value pairs ( which you would find out by simply looking at the source code of it )