# How does Java treat primitive type arrays?

Tags: c#, java, arrays, primitive-types

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How are Integer arrays stored internally, in the JVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76549/how-are-integer-arrays-stored-internally-in-the-jvm)

In C#, when you are creating a new array which is a reference type so it puts a pointer onto Stack and object itself in Heap. If you create this array with simple primitive types such as `int`, `double`, etc. what it does is to put the values exactly where they are placed in Heap instead of a pointer which points at another heap address where the content of it stored.

So can someone please explain how this happens in Java? Java use `Integer` (a reference type) in arrays all the time or treats value types as C# does?

```
int[] hello = new int[5];
hello[0] = 2; // C# put this value directly in same slot and doesn't 
//create a wrapping object.
```

I know a thing which is called Wrapping Types in Java which C# doesn't have. C# has auto-boxing but `Int32` lets say not an reference type, but `ValueType` where as `Integer` is an object as opposed to `int`. You can either box a value using `Object o = 5;` or if struct does have a parent class, you can use it too to wrap it up in heap (boxing).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76549/how-are-integer-arrays-stored-internally-in-the-jvm

Comment: No problems there. However, whereas a `List<int>` is fine in C#, Java doesn't like that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5564423/arrays-in-java-and-how-they-are-stored-in-memory

Comment: @theglauber: a dedicated user to find duplicates :)

Comment: @Braveyard, that would ideally describe us all.

Comment: @KirkWoll : You're right though.

Comment: It's funny, whenever i search for something, how often Stack Overflow shows up. Eventually, every web search will point to S.O.

Comment: @theglauber : Google is crazy about indexing SO questions. e.g. my question is already showing up in Google results : http://goo.gl/ROsTf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java is much the same as you describe.

```
int[] hello = new int[5]; // reference hello is on stack, the object is on the heap.
hello[0] = 2; // Java puts this value directly in same slot and doesn't 
              // create a wrapping object.
```

Comment: I really like your answer :) quick and concise...

Answer (score 2):

Java primitive arrays are stored in the heap as arrays of primitives, not of Integers etc. I do not believe that the actual implementation of how they are stored is specified, so a boolean[] may very well be implemented by an int[] in memory

Answer (score 1):

In Java, the Array is considered as an Object whether it holds primitive variables or object type, in java Array has one and only one instance variable called length.

int[] arr = new int[5];

arr here is an object reference array variable, which is stored on the `STACK` if its used `Inside` the method(ie as `local variable`), `But` if its used as an `instance variable`, then its stored inside the object on the `Heap`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Kumar but it doesn't seem we're talking about the same things. I knew those but what I was wondering how Java stored primitive types in Heap using Arrays. Well, I got my answers within previous answers.